# How to install the omnipay's ipay88 package with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, omnipay

Problem 1

```
- dilab/omnipay-ipay88[2.0.0, ..., 2.0.1] require omnipay/common 3.0-beta.1 -> found omnipay/common[v3.0-beta.1] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
- Root composer.json requires dilab/omnipay-ipay88 ~2.0.0 -> satisfiable by dilab/omnipay-ipay88[2.0.0, 2.0.1].
```

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades, and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Composer is new to me so I might do something wrong in installing.

I tried to add the below code in my composer.json file, and then I used the "composer update" command but the same error still occurs. I really need help, I am also quite new to stack overflow. Sorry if my question is not clear enough.

> "require": {"dilab/omnipay-ipay88": "~2.0"}

This is the Github link I am trying to install https://github.com/dilab/omnipay-ipay88

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages in readable form, and your attempts to resolve the errors

Comment: I have updated the question, is this okay now?

Comment: You forgot to add what you've tried to resolve the problem. Also, please be warned that the package you try to install is about three years old and hasn't seen any activity since. This does not look like anything you should use

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but I really need a code for payment with IPay88. The Github code seems workable for me. I have tried to manually install the composer.phar but I think it is not the issue.

Comment: If there is any problem with the package itself, you need to contact the maintainer. Also, `but it does not match your minimum-stability` is a well documented problem. What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually require `omnipay/common` in your main `composer.json` together with `dilab/omnipay-ipay88`:

```
"require": {
    "dilab/omnipay-ipay88": "~2.0",
    "omnipay/common": "3.0-beta.1"
}
```

This is due to `dilab/omnipay-ipay88` using a beta version of `omnipay/common`, and without `minimum-stability` config, Composer will not install any non-stable dependencies that are not required directly in your main `composer.json`.

With the config above, you will work around the `but it does not match your minimum-stability` error message, while keeping your other dependencies stable.